# Writers.SE and NaNoWriMo 2012

Tags: discussion, nanowrimo

With NaNoWriMo about two months away it might be time to start thinking about how we will take part in it this year. Not only can we use this to bring a new round of attention to the site, it can also be used to help grow the community.

Here are a few ideas I've been kicking around:

- Last year we were hoping to have a NaNoWriMo promotion for the site, it would be nice if we could arrange for it this year.
- It might be worth allowing for a limited number of off-topic 'questions' for people to exchange their Nano forum handles as well as current word counts. Sort of a go to place for all of our members who are doing it this year.
- Set up some Nano events in our chat room, two or three a week and at different times. This can also help drive people to the chat so the above 'question' doesn't turn into free form chat.

In addition some ideas for trying to promote Writers.SE through Nano:

- First off, everything that was brought up in [last years thread on the subject](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/is-nanowrimo-a-growth-opportunity-for-writers-se).
- We should make up some Writers.SE swag we can offer at write-ins, maybe just a business card that anyone can print out. It will be useful to give to people if it comes up. If we do this right it would be useful even after Nano is over.
- Try using your Nano forum signature to have your Writers.SE flair (assuming this is possible, I've never been huge on the forums).

Answer (score 3):

For my part, I will make sure I spend extra time in our [Writer's Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) in November for anyone who wants to stop by and chat about how they are doing.

We'll also discuss preparation in our weekly chat and come up with some fun exercises to help get the novel-writing juices flowing.

Also, cookies! And moral support!

Comment: I second cookies. Wish I could make it to the chats at some time other then the late evening.

Answer (score 3):

Any "administrative" questions that get created to support this (forum handles, links to WIP, whatever) should be on meta, not main.

If anybody who's already a regular here is participating, it would be good to think about real, on-topic questions that fit with the timing of NaNoWriMo and ask them at those times.  That way anybody coming here from that will see questions that make them say "hey, that's just what I'm wrestling with now! these guys are cool!".

Comment: It seems reasonable to leave those questions here on meta. That being said, can we make public links to them on the main site so they have visibility to the non-meta users?

Comment: We might want to be a little more lenient on asking questions that have been answered a while ago. That way it will encourage people to provide fresh answers and might help them stick around.

Comment: @FoxCutter, agreed on both.  A mod can mark a meta post as "featured" and that gets it linked on main (in the bulletin board).  For relevant questions that have been asked before but don't have satisfactory answers, this would be a good time to bump them.