# NaNoWriMo topic challenge #1: let's ask about time management!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

We recently called for ideas for topic challenges related to NaNoWriMo. With NaNo starting Saturday, here's the first challenge: as NaNo gears up, what [time-management challenges](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/917/1993) are you facing?  What questions do you have about planning and executing a large project in a small amount of time, when you can't just wait for the muse to strike or give yourself a week off?<sup>1</sup>

From now through the middle of NaNoWriMo, if you ask a question related to this challenge please add a link to it in the community-wiki answer below.  On November <s>9</s> 20 I'll count up the scores of each question *and* all its answers and announce a "winner" -- but really, we all win by getting people good answers to their questions!

What do you win?  A better Internet and bragging rights.  (Sorry, we don't have goodies to hand out.)

<sup>1</sup> The inspiration for this challenge is NaNo, but there are lots of other times when we writers can be under pressure to deliver something quickly. So don't feel like you have to limit yourself to asking about NaNo projects; that thesis deadline or software-doc delivery counts too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add links to questions for this challenge here: