# NaNoWriMo topic challenge #2: let's ask about ad-hoc plotting

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

We recently called for ideas for topic challenges related to NaNoWriMo. I'll leave our [previous challenge](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/928/1993) open, but meanwhile here's challenge #2: let's ask questions about [plotting and plot holes](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/1993).  If you've developed a detailed outline then you might have this nailed, but for the rest of us -- how do you keep track of loose ends?  How do you push past them to keep writing?  How do you keep your story coherent?  What other challenges do you run into?  If you've faced these problems, how about asking questions about them on main?

For the next week and a half, if you ask a question related to this challenge please add a link to it in the community-wiki answer below. On November 20 I'll count up the scores of each question and all its answers and announce a "winner" -- but really, we all win by getting people good answers to their questions!

What do you win? A better Internet and bragging rights. (Sorry, we don't have goodies to hand out.)

The inspiration for this challenge is NaNo, but there are lots of other times when we writers can be under pressure to deliver something quickly. So don't feel like you have to limit yourself to asking about NaNo projects; that thesis deadline or software-doc delivery counts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add links to questions for this challenge here:

[Is pantsless writing practical for NaNoWriMo?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/is-pantsless-writing-practical-for-nanowrimo)